# Having trouble with kv scrollbar

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

I'm trying to implement a scrollbar in my app but I don't know how to do it. Can you help me?
I tried to follow some tutorials, but I didn't manage to find one that explained clearly what to do. This is a "collage" made by all those tutorials.

Here's the code.

```
ScrollView:
        size_hint: 1, None
        size: root.width, root.height
        do_scroll_x: False

        GridLayout:
            id: output
            cols: 1
            height: self.minimum_height

            # Then i tried to add some buttons to see if it worked, but without success.
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: All the ScrollView children must have at least one of size_hint(x or y) set to none. If you want to scroll in y-axis set the property size_hint_y of the GridLayout to None

Comment: Thanks man this helped me a lot